# Change arg in function using empty interface

Tags: string, function, go, integer

I'm using Golang and I have a question:

I can write this function:

```
func newprint(a interface{}){
    switch a.(type){
    case int:
        fmt.println("this is integer")
    case string:
        fmt.println("this is string")
    case float:
        fmt.println("this is float")
}
}
```

I want to use a function that uses an empty interface and change arg based on its type.
For example:

if type of arg was `int i` want to add 2 units to it
if type of arg was `float i` want to add 5 units to it and
if type of arg was string just print it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify a variable, pass a pointer to the variable to the function:

```
func newChange(a interface{}) {
    switch a := a.(type) {
    case *int:
        *a += 2
    case *float64:
        *a += 5.0
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
a := 1
newChange(&a)
```

[Run this program on the GoLang PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/QAK1d-A2KJY).

Comment: thats true...i knew i have to use pointers but i made a mistake in syantax while uning it..thx buddy..you helped me a lot..thank you